# how to find the links in the footer in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to find the links in the footer of a magento website , but i am having difficulty finding the phtml file. I found the block code in the page.xml file

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" after="footer.newsletter" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
```

but i cannot find the file links.phtml file , i checked the current template

```
website/app/design/frontend/website.com/default/template/page/
```

but i cannot see any template folder there.

Can anybody help me please with this, how to find the file, i even tried turning on template path hints it didn't help. Thanking you for your help in advance.

Comment: have you tried **adding** a `links.phtml` **to** `app/design/frontend/website.com/default/template/page/`??  It could just be reverting back to `default/default` is my guess because it doesn't exist.

Comment: nope i could not find it in default/default also, and the links are already there i just need to find it and change something on it

Answer (score 2):

It can be confusing, the footer links i Magento are generated in one of two ways:

**1)** Added via XML layouts, which is how the sitemap link etc are added, example:

**contacts.xml**

```
<reference name="footer_links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="contacts" ifconfig="contacts/contacts/enabled">
          <label>Contact Us</label>
          <url>contacts</url>
          <title>Contact Us</title>
          <prepare>true</prepare></action>
</reference>
```

You can add more like this, or comment out to remove each link

They are generated using a standard template file (template/page/template/links.phtml) which is enabled in the config below. Each link definition as above (there's multiple in different xml configs) will use the template below to display the actual HTML link.

**page.xml**

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
     <!-- uncomment this to ditech them.. -->
     <block type="page/template_links" 
            name="footer_links" as="footer_links" 
            template="page/template/links.phtml" />
 </block>
```

**2)** You will find a static block called footer_links which also includes some links, this is to make it easier for you to add your own link. They are enabled inside

**cms.xml**

```
<reference name="footer">
    <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links" before="footer_links">
       <!--
         The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id.
         You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks
       -->
       <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Both methods are used to generate the footer links which can be confusing :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this path:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/template
```

Hope that helps you...

Answer (score 0):

to remove "orders and returns" from the footer link i had to comment out the block from sales.xml file

```
  <!-- <default>
       <reference name = "footer_links">
       <block type="sales/guest_links" name="return_link"/>
       <action method="addlinkBlock">
       <blockName>return_link</blockName>
       </action>
       </reference>
       </default>
   -->
```